# Are Websites Hosted on Azure with Dreamspark subscriptions publicly accessible?

Tags: asp.net, azure, dreamspark

I'm a computer science student with a Microsoft Dreamspark subscription. I recently created a website which I'm trying to host on Azure. The website URL is nickgilbert.azurewebsites.net. Whenever anybody besides me tries to access it they get hit with a sign-in wall prompting the user to sign into their Microsoft account. Can I fix this so the website is publicly accessible or does Dreamspark only let the subscription holder see the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting of Azure apps from dreamspart subscript are [free of cost](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99). Are you using any Authentication mechanism in your website? Make sure you have anonymous access enabled to your default page in your app.

Comment: Yeah I just found it, I had Authentication turned on in the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure student web sites are open to the world you simply need the url..

Did you set this up using a template? Here some instructions of how to setup a ASP.NET web site on Azure Cloud http://showtheworld.info/Quick_Start_Azure_Webapp.pdf